# Compile error when using std::cout between if/elseif statements

Tags: c++

I was wondering why I get a compile error when I try to use std::cout in between, say, an if statement and else if statement.
For example:

```
if (condition)
{body}
std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
else if (condition)
{body}
```

Gives the error

```
error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
```

Comment: You forgot to put the `cout` inside the `if` block (between the `{...}`).

Comment: Is the output *supposed* to be outside of the `if` body?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "else if" statement. The forms of conditional are `if (condition) body` and `if (condition) body1 else body2`. `body2` can of course be a conditional of the same forms.

Comment: Why wondering? The error message is clear. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let me get this right first:
You want to execute the *cout* statement in between the conditional no matter whether the condition was met or not, i.e. no matter whether the body of the *if* got executed or not.

As previous commenters noted, you cannot place something between the end of scope of the if-block and the `else` keyword.

What about approaching this by splitting up the if-else-if block into two separate if-blocks:

```
if (condition1) {
    body1
}
cout << "hello world" << endl;
if (!condition1 && condition2) {
    body2
}
```

Comment: @downvoters: please comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's why indentation is important

```
if (condition)
{   body
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
else if (condition)
{    
    body
}
```

In your code, cout is outsite the if block, so no more else is expected.

Comment: It is also why indentation is not important.   Indenting a statement does not change the meaning of code - for the compiler - in any way.  For example, by grouping it with preceding statement.

Comment: You're right @Peter, I meant that correct indentation would have made the error obvious to dustinyourface... Let's agree on "That's why autoindent is helpful" maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add any executable code between if and else if other than the enclosed body of the if and else if loops.

```
if (firstCondition)
{ 
    /*code for firstCondition*/ 
    //code anything here   
}
//not here #######
else if (secondCondition)
{
    /*code for secondCondition*/ 
    //code anything here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct is:

```
if (condition)
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
else if (condition)
{body}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be an option for you.

```
   if (fistCondition)
   { 
        /*code for fistCondition*/ 
        std::cout << "hello first" << std::endl;
   }
   else if (secondCondition)
   {
       /*code for secondCondition*/ 
       std::cout << "hello second" << std::endl;
   }
```

If you wanna call the `cout` in any case between the first and second condition, then avoid the `else` keyword and apply two `if` statements.

```
     if (fistCondition)
     { 
         /*code for fistCondition*/ 
         std::cout << "hello first" << std::endl;
     }
     std::cout << "posterior to first and prior to second if statement" << std::endl;
     if (secondCondition && !firstCondition)
     {
         /*code for secondCondition*/ 
         std::cout << "hello second" << std::endl;
     }
```

In this case, `&& !firstCondition` emulates an `else` keyword for your purpose.